# Why does c++ return this result

Tags: c++

When i want to calculate the complement of 0  i get -1 as an answer.I thought it should be a big number,as it is 11111111 (i don't know how many bits are used i just wrote for 8)  in binary number system.

Comment: All ones is -1 in twos complement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an `unsigned` integral type. Bitwise operations on signed integers have plenty of implementation-defined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

When values are interpreted in 2s complement, all bits set is `-1`.

Comment: Isn't it the other way round? "When 'all bits set' is interpreted as 2's complement, it expresses the value -1." You can't really "interpret an integer".